# JavaScript get document data from URL

Tags: javascript, url

Is it possible to get html document info(`document.getElementById('something')`) from a URL?
here's a better example:

```
var box1 = url('https://example.com').document.getElementById('header');
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to make an AJAX request, parse the received HTML and extract one or more DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jQuery if it is available in your project.

```
$( "#box1" ).load( "https://example.com #header" );
```

Keep in mind that the above is subject to cross-domain rules, and the ajax request does still load the entire example.com document, however only the matching selector portion is injected in your div.

Comment: I just tested this, and it only works on the site that you are fetching. I tried multiple, but they don't work. I don't know if i did it wrong, but i also know nothing about ajax

Comment: Thats what I meant by cross-domain rules in my answer. either it will need to be the current site, or you will need to be authorised in their crossdomain.xml file

Comment: If you need to rip somthing off another person's site, you won't be able to do that with javascript, and will need a server-side script to fetch the data.